# Can regexes capture a substring without using groups?

Tags: .net, regex

The regex `foo/(\w*)/bar` matches the string `foo/123/bar`.

This is probably something basic that I've missed about regexes, but often I only want to retrieve the substring between the slashes. Is there a simple .NET API I can use without having to access the groups collection? Or an alternative way of writing the regex?

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, the groups are how you access substrings in regular expressions. What is wrong with using the groups collection? With named groups it becomes a very clean way to access parts of the regular expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible using lookaround:

```
(?<=foo/)\w*(?=/bar)
```

applied to foo/123/bar. matches "123". **Groups are a better method** and bear in mind that lookaround (in particular look behind) is not supported in all regex tools, but it is in .net.

note: \w is shorthand for a character class, you don't need to put it inside []

Comment: System.ArgumentException: parsing "(?<foo/)\w*(?=/bar)" - Invalid group name: Group names must begin with a word character.

Comment: typo in the lookbehind, fixed

Comment: When using lookaround you might get overlapping results, for example on: `foo/foo/bar/bar`

Comment: Indeed, in fact, overlapping results are largely the purpose of lookaround!

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no, but it really is no hassle to get the capture:

```
string cap = Regex.Match(inputString, @"foo/(\w*)/bar").Groups[1].ToString();
```

Comment: I would prefer a longer answer! Can you actually back that up? Please answer the question; don't just show me how to access the Groups collection in C#.

Comment: I'm sorry if I offended you, perhaps one of the other answers suits you better.

Comment: Sorry to be short. I'm asking a specific question. If you have any supporting information about *why* the answer is no, then I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 0):

If the string is guaranteed to be matched, and you only want the substring between the two slashes, `String.Split` can be used instead of Regular Expression:

```
String sub = str.Split('/')[1]
```

Comment: Thanks, but the question is about the regex language - this is just an example.

Comment: The point is that I want to *match* the string matched by the regex but *retrieve* the substring in the group.